# How to access a collection through another collection using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First off all, excuse me if the title is not very accurate.

Let's say I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_group
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :records
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_group
    has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :record
end
```

I want to access from the current_user (User) to all the unpaid Invoices of his UserGroup. Something like this:

```
current_user.user_group.records.invoices.where(:payment => false)
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work. The closest approach I've found is this:

```
class UserGroup
  def unpaid_invoices
    records.map{|r| r.invoices.unpaid}
  end
end

class Invoice
  def self.unpaid
    where(:payment => false)
  end
end
```

And then I can do:

```
current_user.user_group.unpaid_invoices
```

However this is not scalable, because when I want to use a new condition, like invoices with amounts bigger than $1000, I need to create two new methods in those models.

There is some magic-rails-way to do this? Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: You can declare inside `UserGroup` something like `has_many :invoices, :through => :records`

Comment: Wo, that's so simple and useful. I feel so noob now :). Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, your solution surprises me because until now I always used `has_many :through` only for Many to Many relationships.

I just saw this approach is also documented in the Rails Guides:

_The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up “shortcuts” through nested has_many associations._

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: posted, by the way, consider using named scope instead of methods (talking about Invoice::unpaid) where possible.

Comment: I switched from scopes to class methods after reading this:
http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like that into UserGroup:

```
has_many :invoices, :through => :records
```